# How can I tell SP installation of an existing SQL server

Tags: sql-server, installation, prerequisites

I wish to install SharePoint 2010 standard server but to "show" it the location of an existing SQL server, rather than have the prerquisites installation install its own sql version on the same machine as the SharePoint server's.

The problem is when I run the prerequisites installation it tries to install SQL server automatically without giving me the option to select an exisitng server.

So, to make the question simple - how do I install SP server and SQL server on separate machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the prerequisites installation which selects sql, but the SharePoint installation.

To run on a real Sql Server select `Server Farm` and then `Complete`, NOT `Standalone` or `Stand-alone`:

[image]
[image]

When you then run the Configuration Wizard you are prompted to select the SQL server:
[image]

Images taken from [How to Install SharePoint 2010 on Small Farm – Part 1: Full Installation on Small Farm up to Managing Service Applications](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/06/09/how-to-install-sharepoint-2010-on-small-farm-part-1-full-installation-on-small-farm-up-to-managing-service-applications/)

Comment: OK. Worked just like said. I only wonder about this - why should the prerequisites installaton install the express SQL version automatically when there's a chance I would like to create a farm with a separate SQL server?

Comment: There should be no Sql Express in prereqs, there is a couple of SQL libraries, but that's all.

Comment: You can see even in the guide you linked to that the preparation tool installs microsoft SQL server 2008 native client.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 native client is a client library for accessing a SQL Server it's not the SQL server. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937733)

Answer (score 1):

it's an old post but just to precise a point. SQL Server Express Edition or Standard/Entreprise edition is needed in the Install. 
Following the above links in the article. Per Jakobsen said that only SQL Server Native client is mandatory it's not true. 
SQL Server Native Client is mandatory in the preparation tool (to communicate with SQL Server Express or other edition) of the install, next step will be to install the server farm and indicates a SQL Server 2008 instance or the standalone  with SQL server 2008 express installed by default. this is because SharePoint need a content database to work in every topology.